# Trouble Running main.dart in a Flutter Project: Missing Code or Configuration?

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

I am working on a Flutter project and encountered issues while trying to run `main.dart`. Below is the code snippet from my `main.dart` file:

```
void main() async {
  // initialize hive
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  // open a box
  await Hive.openBox("Habit_Database");
 

  
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.nunitoTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme:
               ColorScheme.light(primary: ColorsToAPP.selectText)),
      home: const StackePages(),
    );
  }
}
```

Despite following the documentation and ensuring all packages are correctly installed, I cannot run the application. The error messages are not clear, making it difficult to pinpoint the issue. Is there a specific piece of code or configuration I am missing? How can I successfully run `main.dart` without encountering these problems?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the code that will actually run the app:

```dart
void main() async {

...

  runApp(MyApp());

}
```